# Error while sharing IPA file , iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, sharing, ipa

I am using xcode 4.2 and iOS-5 SDK for developing my application.

I have recently renewed my developers profile. Before this I could easily create IPA file of my app and share. But now I am getting following error while sharing IPA file.

```
error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Developer: xxxxxx --resource-rules=/var/folders/9-/9-vSr3vSHg4KChJwacq7bE+++TI/-Tmp-/yMDg5KNfD0/Payload/myApp.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/9-/9-vSr3vSHg4KChJwacq7bE+++TI/-Tmp-/yMDg5KNfD0/Payload/myApp.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/9-/9-vSr3vSHg4KChJwacq7bE+++TI/-Tmp-/yMDg5KNfD0/Payload/myApp.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources
```

I can run my application from Xcode directly but sharing IPA file is problem. 
Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

After renewing the developers profile for the first time I have learnt to ensure two things

1. In the build settings select don't code sign and then select the profile.
2. On the device, before installing the app through iTunes, make sure the renewed profile is installed

We have renewed several profiles since and these two steps were all we needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I first selected dont code sign and then the profile but i am getting same error. for the second point you mentioned I am not able to save (share) IPA file so any check while installing from itunes is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change the code sign for both the project and the target.